# How do I programatically force Chrome to show PDF file in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, download, tabs

I am aware that one can do this manually (hold Ctrl down when clicking the PDF link).

But I need a solution like this:

-- when a user  clicks on the link that generates the PDF, Chrome will  either display the PDF in-browser **in a new tab**

or

-- override that behavior and show the download dialog.

Any ideas?

MORE INFO:

On my page there is a form that is submitted to generate the PDF. The form is submitted using a combination of `anchor` and `jquery submit`.

The PDF is then returned to the browser - on FF I get the download dialog, but on Cr I get the PDF loaded in the same tab.

```
//form elements

<a id="submit" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/#">download pdf</a>


<script>

$('#submit').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#lost_form').submit();

});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I am having different question--> "How do I download the pdf file instead of opening them in chrome browser "<<>>>Currently Chrome provides its own viewer, I am not allowed to switch off chrome viewer because i can not ask each user to switch off chrome viewer.  Is there any more alternative for this

Comment: Sorry for asking question here, I am blocked from asking question that's why i am asking question here ?.... hope someone will help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link to the PDF, use [`target="_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/A#attr-target), like so:

```
<a href="//path/to/document.pdf" target="_blank">PDF link text</a>
```

If you want to make the PDF download instead of open in-browser, you need to set the [`Content-Disposition` HTTP response header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#Responses) to something like

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=document.pdf
```

Comment: thx @matt ball -- I just added more info -- the `target="_blank"` alone does not work, PDF still opens on same tab

Comment: Since you're submitting a form, put the `target` attribute on the `form` element. Semantically, though, you should stick to using a `<input type="submit"/>` to submit forms.

Answer (score 2):

`onclick` open a new window, with your PDF path in this url

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo $pdffilefath;?>&embedded=true
```